# How can I create a CSV file and append content to it, in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to save some information about servers into a csv file. The information that will be saved to this file will be added like a cycle, so, in a way, I need to append information to the file.

I have tried two ways of doing this, but none of them seem to work (the variables ip, id, name and stauts, will not be static in the final version of the script):

1. with Add-Content

   ```
   for($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++){
    $OutFile = "C:\information.csv"

    $test = Test-Path -Path $Outfile

    $id=$i
    $ip="1234$i"
    $name="Server$i"
    $status="up"

    if(!$test)
   {

       Add-Content -Path $Outfile -Value '"ID","IP","Name","Status"'

   }
   ```

   Add-Content -Path $OutFile -Value $id,$ip,$name,$status

   }

When I run this script, all of the information is put in the same column/header.

[image]

2. Creating empty CSV file and add content to it:

   ```
   for($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++){
   $OutFile = "C:\information.csv"

   $test = Test-Path -Path $Outfile

   $id=$i
   $ip="1234$i"
   $name="Server$i"
   $status="up"

   if(!$test)
    {
       $newcsv = {} | Select "ID", "NAME","IP","STATUS" | Export-Csv $OutFile
    }


   $csvfile = Import-Csv $OutFile

   $csvfile.ID = $id
   $csvfile.NAME = $ip    
   $csvfile.IP = $name
   $csvfile.STATUS = $status


   $csvfile | Export-CSV $outfile –Append


   }
   ```

When I run this script I get error messages for each header saying:

> The property 'ID' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
> property exists and can be set.

However, the file is created and the information is put in the correct header, but the content of each header is wrong, and the ID header has a different value from the variable that I created

[image]

I way bests suits to append values to a csv file, and what I' doing wrong to have the outputs shown in the pictures?

I'm available to respond to any question regarding this problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't need to test (`Test-Path`), create and/or load your `Csv` file (`Import-Csv`). Just `Export-CSV $outfile –Append` is enough to ***create a CSV file and append content to it, in powershell***

Comment: I need the test path just to check if the path exists. If it exists it will only append information and not create the file from scratch

Comment: `Export-CSV $outfile –Append` will **create** the file (and immediately add contents) if *doesn't* exist and **append** the contents if it *does* exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For outputting a valid CSV, collect objects and use `Export-Csv`.

Try something like this:

```
$OutFile = "C:\information.csv"

# output 5 dummy servers
0..4 | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Id     = $_
        IP     = "192.168.1.$_"
        Name   = "Server$_"
        Status = 'Up'
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $Outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Output when shown on screen:

```
Id IP          Name    Status
-- --          ----    ------
 0 192.168.1.0 Server0 Up    
 1 192.168.1.1 Server1 Up    
 2 192.168.1.2 Server2 Up    
 3 192.168.1.3 Server3 Up    
 4 192.168.1.4 Server4 Up
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to do this without specifying the number of loops. I just added the for loop for people to understand that the script will be done multiple times and it will append info each time. However, the final version of the script won't have the for loop

Comment: @Sam Have you _tried_ just removing the loop? `[pscustomobject]@{ Id = 1; IP = "192.168.1.1"; Name='Server1'; Status='Up'} |Export-Csv -Path C:\path\to\information.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Exactly what I was looking for. It turns out it's a very simple script. Thank you again for your time